# FLASK Web application with (dynamically) changing sequential workflow

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, flask-wtforms

I need to build a web application that represents a sequential workflow. On each page, the user fills a form, and on submit, she is redirected to the next page. The forms do not depend on each other.

So for example, say we have 6 pages, `A, B, C, D, E, F`
the workflow would be

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

Yet, it is very well possible that the the order of the sequence will change frequently over time, or even be newly composed for each user based on dynamic information. A new sequence may be for example (re-ordered and leaving out 2 steps)

```
B -> A -> C -> F
```

Thus I would like to avoid hardcoding the sequence into the application, e.g. as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447355/python-flask-sequence-of-gets-and-post).

My current approach is to have a dispatcher function `next()` like this

```
def next(current_page)
    if current_page == "/step_a":
        return redirect(url_for("/step_b"))
    elif current_page == "/step_b":
        return redirect(url_for("/step_c"))
    ...
```

and have each view function return

`return next(request.url_rule.rule)`

Is there a better (best practice?) way in flask to define (and easily adapt) such a sequential workflow, especially without hardcoding it into the view functions (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35447788/4480139))?

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem statement, there could be more than 1 way to solve it. One, which you have already stated. Other could be something like internal routing. This would involve a request wrapper . Something like this :

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, render_template
app = Flask("the_flask_module")

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def post_redirect_get():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("post_redirect_get.html")
    else:
        # Use said data.
        return redirect("target", code=303)

@app.route("/target")
def target():
    return "I'm the redirected function"
```